# Get the index of second element matching condition in a rust vec

Tags: rust

Lets say I have something like

```
let v: Vec<bool> = [false, true, false, true, false, false];
```

I want to get the position of the second "true" (So in this case get_second_index(v) should return `Some(3)`) Currently I'm doing the following which I think is pretty ugly:

```
fn get_second_index(v: Vec<bool>) -> Option<u32> {
  let mut num_matching = 0;
  let mut second_index = 0;
  for (i, b) in v.iter().enumerate() {
    if *b {
      num_matching += 1;
    }
    if num_matching == 2 {
      second_index = i;
    }
  }
  if second_index == 0 {
    return None;
  }
  second_index
}
```

Is there any more elegant, more idiomatically rust way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply `.enumerate()` an `Iterator` over the `Vec` to get the indices, then use `.filter_map()` on the enumerated iterator to get all `true`-values, and use `.nth()` on the filtered iterator to get the second match:

```
fn second(inp: &[bool]) -> Option<usize> {
    inp.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .filter_map(|(idx, b)| (*b).then(|| idx))
        .nth(1)
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<bool> = vec![false, true, false, true, false, false];
    assert_eq!(second(&v), Some(3));
}
```

Notice that this will return a `Option<usize>`, not an `Option<u32>`, as all indices are `usize`...

Comment: This is nice. I like it. Thanks!

Comment: @mathmonkey please accept the answer then, so this question is marked as resolved

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```rust
fn get_second_index(v: Vec<bool>) -> Option<usize> {
    let mut matched = false;
    v.iter().position(|x| {
        if matched {
            *x
        } else {
            matched = *x;
            false
        }
    })
}
```